# How to convert seq_len into Rcpp equivalent

Tags: r, rcpp

I just started learning Rcpp, and I'd like to convert the following function into Rcpp:

```
foo <- function(N) {
   out <- c()
   for (i in (seq_len(N-1)+1)){
      out[i-1] <- i + 1
   }
   return(out)
}
```

This is my attempt so far, but it's not quite outputting what I want.

```
cppFunction("NumericVector bar(int N) {
            NumericVector out (N);
            for(int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++) {
            out(i - 1) = i + 1;
            }
            return(out);
            }")
```

Comment: Print the value of `(seq_len(N-1)+1)` for some small `N` and you'll see your error.

Comment: Let N = 3. So currently I know seq_len(N-1) + 1 outputs 2, 3. I just don't know how to perform that using c++

Comment: The R code seems convoluted to me. Why not `for (i in seq_len(N - 1)) out[N] = i + 2L`? Of course, better yet would be using vectorised operations — `foo = function (n) seq_len(n - 1L) + 2L`. Incidentally that’s probably about as fast as the Rcpp code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices in C run from 0 on.
Try

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("NumericVector bar(int N) {
        NumericVector out (N-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < N-1   ; i++) {
          out(i) = i + 3;
        }
        return(out);
        }")

foo(4)
#> [1] 3 4 5
bar(4)
#> [1] 3 4 5
```

`foo` as defined is a bit counter-intuitive because it outputs one element less than its argument `N`